# While opening SAP B1, I am getting error "unable to connect licence server"

Tags: installation, sapb1

I have problem while opening SAP B1. I am installing SQL Server and setting all its services that "automatic". Also I am installing SAP B1 and setting all its service and also "TAO Service" that "automatic" and restarting. But although I have done everything and every solution for this problem, I am getting error that "unable to connect licence server". Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to configure the file C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One\Conf\b1-local-machine.xml, with the correct host and port for LicenseServer and SLDAddress.

*The path may vary depending on you SO and SAP Client version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the client machine hosts file includes the Server name and IP. Considering the latest microsoft updates, this solution was applicable for my case.